# Wild yellow flower in floodplains

Tags: identification, flowers

A friend of mine has this flower in his garden, he took seeds from wild flowers growing in the floodplains of the Lek (branch of the Rhine, in Netherlands). Can anyone ID this flower?

[image: yellow flower]

Comment: It appears to be an evening primrose (*Onagraceae* Family, which includes *Oenothera* and related species), but if so, it's unusual. Onagraceae is a large family and Oenothera is a huge genus, unfortunately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After browsing many photos of endemic wild flowers, I found that it looks very similar to the common wallflower, *Erysimum cheiri*. Especially the [seed pods](https://garden.org/plants/photo/433836/) are recognizable.

Thanks for the other suggestions!